# Unsure how to prove the amount of real roots of the equation $(1+x^2)e^x = k$

Tags: polynomials, roots, discriminant

I'm unsure how to prove the following equation

$(1+x^2)e^x = k$

where $k$ is a constant, has one real root where $k>0$ and no real roots if $k<0$.

So far I know the graph and derivative of $(1+x^2)e^x = 0$, as well as having attempted to use the discriminant for the above question with $a =e^x$, $b=0$ and $c = e^x-k$ however I don't seem to get an appropriate answer. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I would write it as $x^2+1 = ke^{-x}$ and analyse the functions $y = x^2+1$ and $y = ke^{-x}$ to see where there solutions are.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski You're right, I deleted my mistaken comment, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has at most one real root. Let $f(x)=e^x(1+x^2)$. Notice that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)=e^x(1+2x+x^2)\geq 0 ~ \forall x\in \Bbb{R}.$$
I.e, the function is non-decreasing. Therefore it can only attain the value of $k$ at one point, assuming $f$ is never "completely flat".

Answer (score 1):

If $ k\le 0$, there will be no root because

$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R)\;\; (1+x^2)e^x>0$$

assume $ k>0$ and put $$f(x)=(1+x^2)e^x$$

$ f $ is differentiable at $ \Bbb R$ and

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\; f'(x)=(1+x)^2e^x>0$$
$f $ is continuous and strictly increasing at $ \Bbb R $, thus
$ f $ is a bijection from $ \Bbb R$ to

$$(\lim_{-\infty}f,\lim_{+\infty}f)=(0,+\infty)$$

So
$$(\forall k>0) \;\; (\exists\; ! \;x\in \Bbb R)\;:\;f(x)=k$$